# PayPal PreApproval Payment with windows 8 phone

Tags: c#, windows-8, paypal, paypal-adaptive-payments

I'm looking for PayPal SDK for windows 8 phone to perform PayPal PreApproval payment. Is there any idea how to do that windows 8 phone?

Comment: https://github.com/paypal/Windows8SDK

Comment: @EhsanUllah, I could not find option for PayPal PreAproval payment in sdk. It just a buy button.